# AEM Query result is not in same order

Tags: aem, jcr

We have a JCR query which will get the result of pages based on jcr:title property. There is no issue in the query and it is working as expected. When we run the query in two different AEM versions(6.0 & 6.4) the order is not same but we see the exact result.  Both AEM versions don’t have any custom index and sorting mechanism but the end result is not having any same order.

Has there any order logic implemented in AEM 6.4? What should we do in order to get the same order in AEM 6.0 and AEM 6.4? Can anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you specify order in the query? Without exact specifics, it's hard to help.

You say "Both AEM versions don’t have any custom index and sorting mechanism but the end result is not having any same order."   If you don't specify order in the query, then the order is really up to the underlying engine and you cannot expect the same results.  If you want an order, you should probably specify that as part of the query.

Different node types also could affect the query, as some node structures preserve order but others do not.

AEM 6.0 and 6.4 are based on different versions of Oak, so there may be some engine changes.

Comment: We dont have different node type, same content in two aem instances. Yeah, you are correct - The result order is different due to different Oak version.